# Netlogo BehaviorSpace reporters

Tags: netlogo, reporters, behaviorspace

I have a netlogo model that was created for me that is GIS-based and calculates CO2 emissions made by passenger vehicles, depending on slope and speed.

It is apparently working fine and I have no issues with it. However, I am trying to do a BehaviorSpace analysis and can't do something I need.

I set the variables to be varied for different types of cars (electric + hybrid + old, middle and new combustion vehicles) and the emissions-diffusion-rate in increments of 0.1.

I'm having trouble inserting the reporter information to measure runs. I have the following globals declared:

```
  total-ev-emissions
  total-hybrid-emissions
  total-combustion-emissions-old
  total-combustion-emissions-middle
  total-combustion-emissions-new
  emission-data
```

How can I ask BehaviorSpace to represent the emissions for each of these globals in every run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your globals contain the results you want, just enter them as the reporters. Just add this in the "Measure runs using these reporters" box (or--just the names of whatever global variables you want as output):

```
total-ev-emissions 
total-hybrid-emissions 
total-combustion-emissions-old 
total-combustion-emissions-middle 
total-combustion-emissions-new 
emission-data
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried it but it didn't work. But... this wasn't the problem after all. I didn't have the right setup and go commands. Once I updated them to correspond to the model's buttons, things started to work.
In conclusion,  some of the things I tried (where the provided answer was one of them) were correct, but setup and go procedures were wrong. Thank you very much for your help anyways, I really appreciate it.